# Primefaces dataTable: No allowUnsorting attribute?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefacs 6.2.17. I have a [dataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml?jfwid=9dc03) where column-header can be clicked in order to sort the table by that column. Clicking the column-header multiple times will swap between ascending and descending ordering. This means that once the table is sorted by that column, I the user cannot go back to not-ordering by that column, but I would like to be able to turn that ordering off. The [dataTables Server API](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/datatable) shows that there is an attribute `allowUnsorting` , which should produce the desired behaviour.

However, this attribute doesn't seem to be available for me, meaning that my programming IDE which usually suggests all available attributes to me does not suggest this one and that adding it to my code has no effect. I assume this is because of my low Primefaces version. I am part of a bigger project and thus I can't simply decide to update the Primefaces version because I would need it for some small feature I want to implement.

This leads me to 2 main questions:

- **Where can I see when some feature/attribute was added to confirm
  whether or not it is available in my version?**
- **What are the options for solving my problem (allowing unsorting) when the feature isn't available for my version?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was added in 10.0, you can always check the docs or the GitHub issue lists and target version

I dont think there is an easy way to add this feature to your old version. I would upgrade your version!